# NTAG216 lock bytes security

Tags: encryption, wireless, nfc

I want to ask about the "lock bytes" implemented on the NTAG216 by NXP.
What exactly are these and how do they work? Are they a standard or is it some proprietary technology by NXP?

Are there any papers on it?

Comment: It is difficult to answer "Is it safe enough" without an understanding of the intended uses and possible attacks. For example, it is probably not safe from the NSA if they're motivated, but is safe from opportunistic attacks (unless this sort of security becomes commonplace). Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 2):

Without having any knowledge on the device, from a security point of view, this statement from the product description:

> This app will ensure your xNT cannot be accidentally or maliciously be forever locked into a read-only state.

is somehow fishy.

To be able to hold that claim, thete must be some backdoor. Problem with backdoors is: You never know who uses them.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. DO YOU know any specific attack vectors??

Comment: And I'm telling you: no, but the quote indicates that there must exist at least one.

Comment: The security mesures it uses are standard? If yes, what are they? What do they use?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//security.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 2):

Technology marches on. Regardless of how secure that chip is now, in a few years:

- You will need to change the chip (or at least stop using it), because someone will have broken the physical security measures or the software on it.
- You will need to change the key (or at least revoke it and stop using it), because someone will have broken the algorithm, or just because computing technology will have progressed, or because your backup copy of the key has been compromised (or, if this is a signing key for which you keep no backup, because your backup copy of the revocation has been leaked).

These concerns apply no matter what you store in that chip.

How problematic these issues are depends on what you'll be using the keys for and on how much you like having this implant changed every few years.

Comment: After the first unsuccessful use it gets easier: simply slap another tag to the prosthetic limb.

Comment: PLEASE, read my question. I asked about thr IT security of the chip

Comment: @ttouch I have read your question and given it the answer it needs. Sorry if that's not the answer you want to hear. Also please read ["Is (x) Secure" Question Anti-Pattern](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/is-x-secure-question-anti-pattern).

Comment: @ttouch To put it another way: I'm telling you that 1. in a few years, the security of the chip will be broken; 2. one aspect of IT security is what happens if part of it is breached; 3. without a specific use case, “is it secure?” is meaningless anyway, but some concerns apply to every use case and I mentioned those.

Comment: The question is about the implemented software security on the device.

Comment: @ttouch - I think Gilles is saying that the security of the chip will decrease over time, making your proposed strategy very costly due to the constant need to upgrade.